# Emacs 24 with AUCTeX in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installing, emacs, auctex

I installed AUCTeX from the Emacs package manager.
Then I configured it by typing `./configure OPTIONS`.

It doesn't complain and I typed `make` and `make install`.
I tried to open a simple LaTeX document.

I can compile it using `C-c C-c` and default view, then using view command `xdvi filename.dvi` and then it successfully generate a document.

But WYSIWYG feature of AUCTeX is not working.

When I click `Generate Preview` from the Emacs menu bar, nothing happens.

I tried the command `M-x preview-latex` as well, but it has `[no match]`

Did I miss anything during installation?

Comment: you need to `M-x preview-buffer` or `C-c C-p C-b`. A minimal working example would help.

Comment: `Generate previews` is not an active item! It is the beginning of the following items in the menu. The real commands are `preview-buffer`, `preview-region`, `preview-section`, etc.